# CreateServer will not create object in vbscript on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: dll, vbscript, asp-classic, interop, windows-server-2008-r2

I have read a few solutions for this problem but none of them have worked for me.  One of the main problems is that I am fairly sure I have a 32-bit dll that I am trying to use and I am trying to run it on a 64-bit server.  Also I do not have the source code for the Interop dll. Most of the solutions I found involved making changes to the DLL and recompiling.

I have registered this dll using RegAsm.exe.  The dll resides in the C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder.  It appeared to have registered fine, there were no errors.

I am trying to migrate a classic ASP web site from Windows Server 2003 (IIS 6) to Windows Server 2008 R2 (IIS 7.5).

One solution I found mentioned something about creating a VBS script and running that in the SysWOW64 folder.  I'm not sure why running the script in the SysWOW64 folder was important but I did it anyway.  I still cannot create the object.

I just copied and pasted code from my classic ASP page into the VBS script and added the Wscript.echo command.

Below is my VBS script.

```
Dim objCrypt, Key, UID, Pwd
Set objCrypt = CreateObject("MyEncryptionTool.Crypt")
Key = "1234" ' Encryption Key

UID = "äRŸê¬ÈH­" 
Pwd = "á@‰ë•ÆW¬"

Wscript.echo "UID: " & objCrypt.Decrypt(UID, Key) & vbCrLf & "Pwd: " & objCrypt.Decrypt(Pwd, Key)
```

The error message that CScript.exe produces is:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CryptTest.vbs(2, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'MyEncryptionTool.Crypt'
```

This is essentially the same error I am getting in my classic ASP page.

I am fairly sure it was compiled 32-bit and Windows Server 2008 is 64-bit and that may be the source of my problem right there.

Is it possible to use a 32-bit dll on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: I just ran Dependency Walker on my dll.  It says that GPSVC.DLL and IESHIMS.DLL are missing.  And it appears there is a warning for IEFRAME.DLL and SHLWAPI.DLL.  I don't know if this has anything to do with my problem or not.  I'm throwing this out for smarter people than me.

Comment: Yes it's possible.  You need to enable 32 bit applictions in your app pool - it's set to false by default.

Comment: The App Pool I created for my web site did have Enable 32bit applications set to True but the DefaulAppPool was False.  Unfortunately when I set the DefaultAppPool to True nothing changed.  CreateObject still does not create the object.

Comment: You should listen to your dependency walker. If your DLL is missing dependencies then it will not load! Ahh, the good old days of DLL Hell just don't want to become the good old days!

Comment: Perhaps but some of the answers to the question of these two dlls not being on Win 7 or 2008 R2 suggested that they aren't necessary.  But I could not find anything definitive saying they are or are not necessary.

Comment: Has your DLL been built for COM? Don't expect it to work if the DLL doesn't expose any interface to COM. Also use `regsvr32` to register DLLs. If registering a 32 bit DLL use `regsvr32` in the `Windows\SysWOW64` folder instead of the `Windows\System32` folder.

Comment: The AppPool you use doesn't matter as long as it has `Use 32 Bit Applications` enabled.

Comment: Lankymart - I don't know any of the specifics of how this dll was created.  It was created before I started here and by a completely different group in different location and it is no longer supported within the company.  I thought at first it was old enough to have been an ActiveX dll created in VB6 or C++ but I at least found out that it was written in dot net.

Comment: Lankymart - RegSvr32 would not register it, that is why I used RegAsm. I ran the version in the SysWOW64 folder. Does this mean that I am out of luck?  I did write my own in VB.Net (VS 2008) a few months ago but we decided that we should stick with this other encryption dll.

Comment: One other thing. I just unregistered the dll with regasm and tried registering it with regsvr32 (in the SysWOW64 folder) and got the following error: "The module "Interop.MyDLL.dll was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found. Make sure that "Interop.MyDll.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX and then try again.

Comment: Lankymart - I have another question.  If this dll was built for COM wouldn't it show up in Components Services?  I do not see it there.  I just do not have enough experience with creating dll's.  I have only written maybe 3 in my life time and I have been programming for 25 years (pretty sad that I don't know more about that subject, isn't it.  But then that is why I am here bugging people with my petty questions).

Comment: The fact it's a .Net assembly means you were on the right track in the first place, but you might be running the x64 version of `regasm` instead of the x86 (32 bit) version.

Comment: Thanks Lankymart for all your help.  When I first ran the RegAsm command I realized after I registered it that I used the version of RegAsm found in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727.  But when I realized I registered it with the 64bit version I unregistered it and then tried it again with the RegAsm found in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727.  This was all done before I created this question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Can you see `MyEncryptionTool.Crypt` in the C:\Windows\Assembly directory?

Comment: Nathan,  thanks for the inquiry.  I realized that I had not posted the resolution on this page.  I have found the resolution to this problem and I just posted the answer.  Had I found my company's documentation on this dll sooner I would have never posted this question here.  I work for a large multi-national company so it took awhile to find the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I should have posted the answer to this back in December 2014 when I figured it out.  It was a stupid operator error.  There are two dll files for the company's encryption tool.  One has the prefix "interop." and the other doesn't.

I was using the one with the "interop." prefix because at the time that was the only dll I knew about.  I found the version without the prefix and registered it with no problem and everything works.  This came about when I finally found some documentation on the company's encryption tool and it never mentioned the dll with the prefix.